# Convert hexadecimal value into bigint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am getting some trouble converting a string (representing a  hexadecimal number) into a bigint. I would also like this to happen inside a function and as effiecient as possible. 
Is there anyway of exploiting the built-in functions?
Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
select convert (bigint, '0000010d1858798c')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SQL Server 2008 release updated the [`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) function to be able to convert hexadecimal values:

```
select convert(bigint, convert (varbinary(8), '0x0000010d1858798c', 1))
```

Result:

```
1155754654092 (decimal) ( ==  0x0000010d1858798c )
```

Comment: yes, thx :D
I used your method and it works perfectly :D
There is only one problem with strings that have odd length but I appended a 0 and now it is ok :D